# symfony built-in server high cpu usage

Tags: php, symfony

I'm running Symfony's built-in server during development and noticed that CPU usage of CLI.exe (PHP's command-line interface that's called through `php bin/console server:run`) is always around 30%, even when idle.

I launch it from a Windows Powershell. Any idea why this happens during idle time?

Comment: What are you expecting pluppfisk. This is not the way to run Symfony, and @Chris is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PHP's built-in web server is only meant to be used during development](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

> **Warning** This web server was designed to aid application development. It may also be useful for testing purposes or for application demonstrations that are run in controlled environments. It is not intended to be a full-featured web server. It should not be used on a public network.

It makes no performance guarantees, and I'm not surprised that it has high CPU utilization.

The [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/web_server/built_in.html) suggests that it is only meant as a convenience:

> This way, you don't have to bother configuring a full-featured web server such as Apache or Nginx.

Of course, you are free to run a full-featured web server in development if you want something more tuned to real world use.

Comment: Fair enough point, but why does it use CPU when idle. It really shouldn't be doing anything at all.

Using the Apache web server doesn't give you the console and requires more frequent cache clearing, so it's not a proper option at the moment.

Comment: @bluppfisk, it [appears to run an event loop](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/2809a676b55cebd4c6f8a8895ffe286db0704e87/sapi/cli/php_cli_server.c#L2449-L2474). I don't know enough about web servers to know if that's a good approach or not, but it clearly _is_ doing something while it's listening for connections.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Interesting. But also annoying as it makes mobile development difficult - battery drained in 3 hours.

Comment: can I ask what all of you do when developing in Symfony? Just switch straight to production mode and use the web server? Or is there a way to use the Apache server properly without changing to production mode? I regularly run into all kinds of route caching trouble when using Apache in dev mode.

Comment: oh gosh, just found out that if you change your symfony apache vhost configuration line to: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]` instead of using `app.php`, those problems are gone.

Comment: it is much, much slower, though (four times).

Comment: @bluppfisk, typically when I'm working I use whatever development server the language or framework provides. Development servers optimize for iteration and convenience, not performance. In my opinion that's a perfectly reasonable tradeoff.

Comment: "only meant to be used during development" - does development not need performance? :/

Comment: @Darius.V, I believe I've been clear about this. The built-in PHP web server is a quick-and-dirty solution optimized for iteration and convenience, not for performance. Technology is about tradeoffs (for example of time vs. space or developer productivity vs. execution speed), and in many development situations trading performance for convenience is a reasonable thing to do. If it's not a good fit for you, _don't use it_.